# Export/Import a layer as QLR in QGIS 3.4 using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to find a way to export a layer in a QLR file in PyQGIS. I want to do the same as right-click and export to layer definition file.

I know that I have to use `QgsLayerDefinition.exportLayerDefinition` and it needs a `QgsLayerTreeNode` parameter. But I don't know the steps to take a `QgsVectorLayer` and put it in a `QgsLayerTreeNode`.

I also need to do the reverse, load a QLR file and show the layer in QGIS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Export

First, select a layer or a group layer.

```
current_node = iface.layerTreeView().currentNode()
QgsLayerDefinition().exportLayerDefinition("c:/path/of/file.qlr", [current_node])
```

---

## Import

**Solution 1:**

You can import `.qlr` file using `loadLayerDefinitionLayers` method. This method just needs the path of `.qlr` file, and returns a list of layers defined in it. Even if defined one layer.

```
layer_list = QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinitionLayers("c:/path/of/file.qlr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layer_list)
```

**Solution 2:**

Or you can prefer using `loadLayerDefinition` method. In this case you need `QgsProject` reference and root/group node.

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
root = project.layerTreeRoot()

QgsLayerDefinition().loadLayerDefinition("c:/path/of/file.qlr", project, root)
```

Comment: The solution 1 is working, thank you. I also need to do the reverse : export a layer to a QLR file.

Comment: Thank you for the export solution, it works. I guess that unless I keep the currentNode in a variable, the layer must be in the toc to do this? I mean, having a QgsVectorLayer variable is not enough? Since QgsVectorLayer probably doesn't have symbology information.