# Add multiple QLR files in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have more than 100 QLR files, QGIS does not allow me to select multiple and, adding them one by one takes a long time. How can I add them all at once?

Comment: did u search a bit in here ?

Comment: @snaileater search for "add qlr" doesn't bring up anything relevant.

Comment: "load qlr" brought me here : (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351409/export-import-a-layer-as-qlr-in-qgis-3-4-using-pyqgis)  _(5th result of the result page)_

Comment: That's a partial solution - the user would have to loop over selected files and run that python. Without a pyqgis tag on this question I wouldn't presume the user would be comfortable with an incomplete Python solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can select and drag multiple .qlr files from my operating system file browser onto the QGIS window and the layers appear.

I can select multiple .qlr files in the QGIS "Browser" section, right-click, and add them to the project.

It only seems to be the "Add Layer Definition File" that is set to only allow one file to be selected. I wonder if that might be worth a bug report as a possible enhancement to the QGIS bug tracker?